# Using Jena ARQ to access remote repo with basic auth - preemptive

Tags: java, jena, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to use Jena ARQ with a PreemptiveBasicAuthenticator, without success, can anyone help?

Im always getting a 401, although the same request through a rest client, or using openrdf works. Could it be something to do with apache http client and having to set an AuthScope?

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.HttpAuthenticator;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.PreemptiveBasicAuthenticator;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.ScopedAuthenticator;

import java.net.URI;

public class JenaConnect {

    private final static String SPARQLR_ENDPOINT = "https://repo-eh-01.sparqlr.com/repositories/examples-repo";
    private final static String SPARQLR_USERNAME = "examples-repo";
    private final static String SPARQLR_PASSWORD = "XXXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String queryString = "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}";
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        HttpAuthenticator authenticator = new PreemptiveBasicAuthenticator(
                new ScopedAuthenticator(new URI(SPARQLR_ENDPOINT), SPARQLR_USERNAME, SPARQLR_PASSWORD.toCharArray())
        );
        QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(SPARQLR_ENDPOINT, query, authenticator);
        try {
            ResultSet results = queryExecution.execSelect();
            int i = 0;
            while(results.hasNext()) {
                results.next();
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        } finally {
            queryExecution.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you turn on `DEBUG` level logging for your code (or specifically for `org.apache.http`) since this will then print HTTP traces to the logs which will allow you to identify whether the authentication is actually being used

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered in this thread: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201401.mbox/%3CF6F103F1-7205-4E6B-94EB-FEB67129A39A%40sparqlr.com%3E